# Direct upload to S3 without CORS (non-browser)

Tags: rest, upload, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cors

We are developing an API on AWS, using a combination of EC2, SQS and S3. Our frontend servers reside on EC2, and we store all user-submitted data on S3. We don't want to expose our S3 storage to end users, so all submissions are initially pass through the EC2. All our end users are ever aware of is our API endpoints, to which they POST data (normally raw text, up to about 1MB at present), and from which they GET results.

We suspect this model is unlikely to scale, however, as we acquire more users and as data submissions become larger. So we have been looking at alternative ways of managing user input. The most attractive of these seems to be [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), which [S3 now supports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html), and which allows end users to directly upload to S3 without having to initially buffer to EC2. But we are developing an API not a web application, and it seems as if CORS would always require some kind of browser-based Javascript to perform the actual upload. We'll probably have some kind of browser UI for large uploads eventually, but all we want to make available to developers right now is our API endpoints.

So basically we are wondering if there is any other possible solutions we could look at. The most important thing for us at the moment is avoiding making public our backend storage, so that only our API urls are exposed (this is also important because we want to retain the possibility of swapping out our backend storage to something other than S3 in the future). We have also looked at the possibility of allowing users to submit using their own S3 accounts, which some APIs certainly do, but don't find this an unattractive option.

Comment: can u describe the workflow a little more. the user POSTs  (then what) ... there is processing and later GETs. Just describe the workflow more as it relates to a typical processing batch if that is it and user authentication. also what stack, php any tidbits

Comment: @DrewPierce Thanks. Yes, at the moment it's typically a POST, followed by processing by our analysis engine, and results are retrieved by subsequent GETs. We use SQS to enqueue/dequeue inputs and outputs (no data goes into SQS. it just tells the processing engine about new submissions to S3). Our user auth is all handled separately by our API management platform, that's just a single call. Oh, and we're not using a 'popular' language... OK, it's Common Lisp :) Everything works like a charm at the moment, actually, but we're not at scale, and that's what we're concerned about.

Comment: You can use an HTTP PUT to upload a file to S3 both from your API or a JavaScript client on a browser. CORS solves cross domain issues that prevent javaScript clients from sending HTTP requests to S3 but it does not prevents your API from making a normal PUT request.

Comment: @FedericoRaggi Thanks, but the point is that at the moment we specifically wish to expose only our API endpoints (of the form https://api.example.com). We have been handling client POSTs to these endpoints on EC2, then PUTting them on to our S3 storage. But for large or numerous uploads this probably isn't going to be very efficient. Which is why we looked at CORS for possible direct uploads. But that forces us to support some sort of upload UI, which isn't what we want to rely on for everything. Hence my question.

Comment: Amazon suports POST for browser-based upload scenarios like yours. You  mentioned users already use a POST request to upload their data to your API endpoint so hopefully you can modify what you have today to work against Amazon's S3 instead of your API. I believe Amazon allows you to pass a policy object as part of the POST request so you don't need to make your S3 buckets publics or assign individual buckets to each user. Here is the link to Amazon's documentation for browser-based uploads: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html

Comment: @FedericoRaggi Sorry if it wasn't clear, but we are _not_ wanting to do browser-based uploads. I know about doing S3 POSTs, but it's not a question of whether we do POSTs or PUTs. We are trying to figure out if there's any way for non-browser data submissions to our urls = say, from a cURL command - to involve a direct upload to our S3 buckets, but without the data passing through our servers on EC2.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use curl for uploading a file to S3. You can implement and distribute to your users a console application that does the POST or PUT to from the users' machines.

Comment: Chris, i am confused what the main problem is. I thought it was that you did not want to expose all your goodies in S3 to the enduser. that is why i was asking about authentication, wondering if you were struggling with a pattern in PHP or something so users could submit but then just see their results and not have access to all your S3 goodies.

Comment: @DrewPierce Thanks Drew, it's not really a security/authentication issue - we have that all sewn up - but rather that we would prefer not to have our end users aware of our use of S3. At present that's exactly the situation - uploads are buffered initially to our EC2 servers, then passed to S3 storage. A good model for what we'd like to achieve might be DropBox. They use S3, but (as far as I'm aware - correct me if I'm wrong) no-one would be able to infer that directly from their API. It seems likely that for large client uploads for the moment we'll go with a CORS-based browser UI.

Comment: i may be assuming something but why cant the users login thru say a php framework (can get one for 10 bucks on codecanyon). there are 5 or so decent ones up there. the user logins in, selects file(s) to upload. you engine processes them and puts output in say another folder. user can retrieve them. you would have to tweak it to take files from linux or windows up and down from s3. perhap usings s3cmd utility. so the user is totally unaware of s3

Comment: Why do you think it won't scale?  If you build your API servers appropriately and stick them behind an ELB - there's no reason why it wouldn't scale - then you don't have the problem about exposing s3

Comment: ~@PeterH. Thanks Peter - actually that's something we've just recently been looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're looking at alternative solutions to exposing S3...

Personally - I'd just dump from the website to S3 and ensure that the website itself scales. (strip out the queue part for simplicity).... but I've added the following given you did mention looking at SQS.

1. Create a small website with a very simple API that dumps your file
   to SQS
2. Create a small service that services an SQS Create a
   repeatable installation (using userdata / chef / cloudformation
   choose your flavour) for *both* the service and the website
3. Register a launch config, ELB and scaling group for the website - choose your
   scaling parameters
4. Register a launch config and scaling group for
   the service - choose your scaling parameters
5. Provide access via IAM and role profile to the web servers to write to the SQS Queue
6. Provide access via IAM and role profile to the service to read from
   the SQS Queue
7. Provide access to the service to write to S3

This will give you scalability across web service, queue, writing service and S3.